# How can this be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I might not be a native English speaker but I think I've made myself clear when I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050815/count-keys-typed-and-mouse-clicks?noredirect=1#comment1717363_1050815).

- I want to know the **amount** of keys typed and the **amount** of mouse clicks.
- I **do not want a key logger**, because a key logger **do not count letters**, **do not count clicks**.

So, how can [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050815/count-keys-typed-and-mouse-clicks?noredirect=1#comment1717363_1050815) be a duplicate of this [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899498/configure-ubuntu-to-record-every-keystroke-in-every-session)?

Comment: Please note that no moderators were involved in closing your question, so you might want to remove the suggestion that we don't read before acting.

Comment: So what title should I use for those involved? I only know that they have more "power" then normal users.

Comment: No, they were 5 normal users. The only thing special about them is that they have spent enough time on the site to gain the ["cast close votes" privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) which you get when you reach 3000 [reputation points](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). [Moderators](https://askubuntu.com/help/site-moderators) are voted by the community and can be identified by the ♦ next to their name.

Comment: Corrected, thanks and sorry for that.

Comment: No worries. I know the site's rules and terminology are confusing. Believe me, we were all confused in the beginning :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that your question isn't a duplicate, and that the only answer is indeed the one you have given. I have therefore reopened it.

I would also like to point out that this was just an honest mistake. Nobody was attacking you and there was no reason to assume people didn't read your question. It is a bit of a strange request, so I can understand why someone would have been confused by it.